# Unable to create obb conda environment

Tags: git, conda, environment, python-poetry, modulenotfounderror

I was trying to use the openbb_terminal on Google Colab, for that purpose I've tried to install the openbb_terminal onto my system by doing the following:

```
# Clone the OpenBB Terminal repository
#!git clone https://github.com/OpenBB-finance/OpenBBTerminal.git

# Move into the OpenBB Terminal directory
%cd OpenBBTerminal
# Create and activate the 'obb' environment
!conda env create -n obb --file build/conda/conda-3-10-env.yaml
!source activate obb

# Run cleanup script
!build/conda/cleanup_artifacts.sh
# Install dependencies and the OpenBB Terminal through Poetry
!poetry install -E all
```

As directed here on [openbb docs](https://docs.openbb.co/terminal/installation/Source).

However, I've received the following error.

```
/content/GPT-InvestAR/OpenBBTerminal

CondaValueError: prefix already exists: /usr/local/envs/obb

The obb conda environment does not exist
Create it by running:
conda env create -n obb --file build/conda/conda-3-10-env.yaml
/bin/bash: line 1: poetry: command not found
```

I've commented the git clone statement, since that has already been done.

Ultimately, further down, I'm required to do this:
`from openbb_terminal.sdk import openbb`

However, It appears I've been unsuccessful in downloading it, since I'm getting:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openbb_terminal'

To confirm, the files have been cloned on to the system:-

`%ls`
gave,

```
config.json             gpt_scores_as_features.py             OpenBBTerminal/  requirements.txt
convert_html_to_pdf.py  LICENSE                               plots/
download_10k.py         make_targets.py                       questions.json
embeddings_save.py      modeling_and_return_estimation.ipynb  README.md
```

and OpenBBTerminal contains:-

```
build            guess_game.json        openbb_terminal        reviewpad.yaml
CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md   images         poetry.lock        terminal.py
CONTRIBUTING.md      json_validate_exclude.txt  pyproject.toml         tests
custom_pre_commit    LICENSE            pytest.ini         website
examples         MANIFEST.in        README.md
frontend-components  noxfile.py         requirements-full.txt
generate_sdk.py      openbb_platform        requirements.txt
```